# GCP serverless VPC connection make 408 timeout

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, vpc, google-vpc

My cloud functions server needs to access to external service and ip adress needs to be applied to the system prior to access to the service. Since it is serlverless, cloud functions does not have static ip adress. I have searched the way to give static ip adress to cloud functions and it was serverless VPC access at GCP VPC network.
Image below shows my VPC creation.

[image: Serverless VPC access]

Cloud functions VPC connection setting is at below

[image: cloud functions VPC connection setting]

Cloud functions works fine before setting VPC connection. After VPC connection setup, error below is occured.

[image: Error]

Do I need any other setting for VPC connection? or do I need to do something with my server code to get rid of 408 timeout error?

If you know anything about this problem, please share your knowledge. Thank you

Comment: What are the logs in your cloud functions?

Comment: 2022-01-05T04:10:41.675536655Ztestr3dckikyxa5b Function execution started

Comment: 2022-01-05T04:11:41.676937401Ztestr3dckikyxa5b Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'

Comment: It seems like request cannot reach to the server. If i setup VPC connection, do i need additional setting for request?

Comment: I just found that I need to setup cloud NAT and static IP adress. Let me try those setup and try again.

Comment: You may have a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout). Let me know if that helps!